# SSRS Page Numbering

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I will try and explain what I am doing as best I can but if anyone needs any further information please let me know.

I have a SSRS report with a number of different DataSets, one of my DataSets is called Details.  Sitting behind this is a SQL Stored Procedure that brings back a number of applications by date.  The Records will look something like this

```
Application ID      Date       Period      PeriodID

1234                01/05/2017 2017-05     1
2978                01/06/2017 2017-06     2
9982                01/07/2017 2017-07     3
```

There will be multiple applications within each period e.g. if there are 6 application in May they will all get the same Period and PeriodID.

I am using the PeriodID as I am creating a number of tables that I am then putting on a filter to only show the application in May in one table and then doing the same for June and July in separate tables.

Each Table is then getting wrapped in a rectangle as I want to show each one on a new tab when exported to Excel.

This is where I am having an issue, I am wanting to automatically name the tabs based on the Period column e.g. May's tab would be called 2017-05.  The problem is when I go to the Expression option and pick my Dataset "Details" and select "First(Period)" I get 2017-05, which is good but when I then go an repeat the same process for the other tabs I am getting them all called 2017-05, I understand this is because this is the earliest period within my initial dataset "Details" and not what is the earliest period within my filtered dataset per table as explained earlier.  I am not sure how I can name the pages in the way I want, can anyone offer some help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the "Details" part of your expression with the name of the group associated with the particular table. That will change the scope of your expression so it will pick the first period of each table rather than the first period of your entire dataset.

Confusingly the default naming for groups is "details" so you might want to rename each group to make things less confusing.

Comment: Hi tomdemaine, I have tried what you have mentioned as yes I think I might have to rename the group.  At the moment my expression is reading in the PageName =First(Fields!Period.Value, "Details2")  but I get the error "The PageName expression for the rectangle 'Rectangle2' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi tomdemaine, with your help I think I have worked this out, previously I have always wrapped my table/matrix in a rectangle before adding in the page breaks and page names.  I hadn't noticed that I can do this directly on the table.  While doing this I am able to access the correct dataset to pull in the period that I want.  This is great though out of interest I would still like to see why I couldn't access the group by but that might be a battle for another day.  Thanks for the help and I have awarded you the answer as it pointed me in the right direction.